# Using vector images in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm creating a wpf application in VS2019 and I want to use a few vector images as images, not as buttons or anything. I've successfully converted a test image to a .xaml file and the image will even show up in IntelliSense correctly (when viewing the image.xaml file itself), but that's as far as I can get.

I've literally spent all day scouring the web and various tutorials to no avail, but this one is what I'm trying to do: https://msadowski.github.io/WPF-vector-graphics-tutorial/

But if you notice in that tutorial he shows the NASA.xaml file as follows:

```
<ResourceDictionary  xmlns:...>
    <Geometry x:Key="NASA_logogeometry1"...>
    <Geometry x:Key="NASA_logogeometry2"...>
    ...
```

but then later sets the ResourceDictionary Source to "Assets/NASA.xaml" in App.xaml and creates the image object with it's Source set to "StaticResource NASA_logoDrawingImage" in MainWindow.xaml...but it never shows how the logo actually got the key "NASA_logoDrawingImage" for it to be a static resource.

When I do this, giving all 250 Paths in my vector image x:keys, obviously the StaticResource is never found. If I instead of using a Resource Dictionary and wrap the Paths all in a Canvas, I can't set a key in Canvas nor can I set the image's source in MainWindow.xaml,

```
<Image Source="images/image.xaml" >
```

I get the "The component cannot be found" error (Eventhough the file is right there in the images folder in the Solution Explorer.

All I want to do is to use this .xaml vector file in the project as an image. Assuming I start with raw vector data (...), what do I need to do to get this working (i.e. what object to i wrap the Paths with, how to use the key to be able to then use the image.xaml file as a StaticResource, or whatever)?

Comment: A XAML file can not be used as the `Source` of an Image element. Declare a resource of type [DrawingImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.drawingimage?view=netframework-4.8) and write `<Image Source="{StaticResource TheDrawingImageResourceKey}"/>`. Alternatively, declare a [GeometryGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.geometrygroup?view=netframework-4.8) resource and assign that to the `Data` property of a Path element.

Comment: For an overview, start reading here: [Graphics and Multimedia](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/index).

Comment: I hate that. When people write a blog supposedly showing you how to do something and it can't possibly work. Either he accidentally missed out several steps of explanation working with those geometries or he knew what he was doing wasn't going to work. Even the briefest of reviews ought to have spotted option 1.  I'd consider combining those geometries in inkscape so there was just a blue and a red one if the individual bits are never to be used separately.

Comment: @Clemens: I tried to use DrawingImage but it wasn't coming up in IntelliSense. Is there a certain namespace I should use in the <ResourceDictionary> tag to be allowed to use DrawingImages?

Comment: @Andy: I know, right!? I think it's that very step he didn't show is what all of the tutorials seem to not cover clearly. I think Clemens identified it in that the problem is simply not knowing how to wrap the vector data. All the tutorials (like the links in the answer below) seem to be geared towards making the vector image part of a button or something and thus use <Canvas> and <Viewbox> which doesn't seem to want to work as an image.

Comment: Just add a `<DrawingImage x:Key="someKey" .../>` to a ResourceDictionary.

Comment: When I do that it's throwing an error: "The type 'DrawingImage' does not support direct content"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Here's what I did:

1. Downloaded Expression Design 4. With this I could open the image.eps file directly and I exported it as XAML WPF Resource Dictionary. This made the .xaml code all neat substituting all the Paths for GeometryDrawing.
2. Added the image.xaml file to the image folder. Expression wrapped the vectors as a Drawing Brush so I only had to change:

   `<DrawingBrush>
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
               <DrawingGroup.Children>
                     Vector Here...`

to:

```
<DrawingImage>
   <DrawingImage.Drawing>
      <DrawingGroup>
         <DrawingGroup.Children>
                  Vector Here...
```

I think part of this was either DrawingImage didn't like the paths or I wasn't wrapping them correctly.

3. Added the resource declaration in App.xaml as shown in the tutorial.
4. At this point, typing this into MainWindow.xaml:

`<Image Source="{StaticResource KeyNameUsedInImage}"/>`

was still throwing a couple different errors like resource not found. I rebuilt the solution a few times and managed to get the errors to go away by changing image.xaml's Build Action to 'Resource' in Properties, but still no image.

5. Finally I clicked on the Image object above and went to the properties window on the right and went to 'Common -> Source' and clicked the little checkbox to the far right, beyond the "..." button. Hovering on "Local Resource" showed the 'KeyNameUsedInImage' and I clicked on that. Then the image appeared right away.

I've never seen step 5 mentioned in any of the 1000 tutorials I read, so I'm thinking the majority of this was a bug of some sort in VS2019 and step 5 shouldn't be necessary. However, I'm mentioning it in case it helps someone down the road.